# Java, LDAP with MySQL, and authenticating users

Tags: java, ldap, lotus-domino, sasl

There's a few moving pieces to this one, so I'll go through things fairly slowly.

1. I have a java web app that has registered a few thousand users, and stored them in a MySQL DB. The passwords for each user has been hashed using SHA1, plus a bit of extra trickery including a randomly generated salt.
2. I also have an LDAP server setup (OpenLDAP). I've managed to configure it to use the same MySQL DB as above as a datasource.
3. There is a Lotus Domino server. When users register via the java web app they are also added to the domino server.

When the users try to log into the Domino server is where we have the problems. Currently we're using LDAP authentication (on the LDAP server above). It works if passwords are stored in clear-text, or a straight SHA1 hashing, but the LDAP server can't authenticate those users who have their passwords encrypted by the java web app above (it uses SHA1, plus "extras").

So I'm really not sure how to approach things. Someone suggest using LDAP with SASL authentication - but I'm not even sure that would work.... I would have to replicate the same encryption algorithm that is in use in the java web app somehow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into setting up directory assistance on your Domino server.  Start here --> http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/lotus/c2359840.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/b3d4579a610b349885257361004fbdb5?OpenDocument

Hope this helps.